# How can you save results of BigQuery ML.PREDICT as a table using a CREATE TABLE statement?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to save the results of BigQuery's ML.PREDICT as a table with a CREATE TABLE statement?

```
create or replace table table_name as (
    SELECT * FROM ML.PREDICT(...)
);
```

This gives the error "`model_name` is not allowed for this operation because it currently has type MODEL."

But the results from just running `SELECT * FROM ML.PREDICT(...)` look like a table in the "Query results" window and the results are literally saved to a temporary table under Job Information > Destination table. But it seems like we're unable to save these results to a table directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily save the results of BigQuery's ML.PREDICT to a table by using BigQuery UI. You can follow the below steps for your requirement:

Step 1: Use your model to predict the [outcome](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/create-machine-learning-model#use_your_model_to_predict_outcomes).

Step 2: After completion of the above step click the ‘SAVE RESULTS' button.

[image]

Step 3: Select the BigQuery table from the options.

[image]

Step 4: Save the result to the BigQuery table.

Step 5: Click the Save button.

You can also consider using a **`CTE`** to create a temporary table.

You can refer to these [document1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/create-machine-learning-model#use_your_model_to_predict_outcomes) and [document2](https://medium.com/@dipan.saha/getting-started-with-bigquery-ml-a-practical-tutorial-for-beginners-9653329d2cc4)  for the sample query.

Comment: Thanks, I'm hoping to create it programmatically with something like CREATE TABLE. But this is a good workaround for now.